# How to send array to Javascript function from another page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a static site (let's call it settings page), and my Javascript function takes with AJAX data from mysql table and draws table on a HTML document.
It works like a charm - it takes all the data I need and doing it in a proper way. 
Here's my function:

```
function get_people()
{
   $.post("/controller/get_people", function(data,status,xhr)
   {
       if(status=="success")
       {
           people_data = data;
           draw_table();
       }
   }) 
}
```

The thing is, on ANOTHER PAGE I have table with all people and checkboxes next to them. 
I'm checking this checkboxes, clicking a button and I want to get into settings page - and my get_people function will select data from mysql only about people checked on previous page.

technically the problem is - how can I pass an array to javascript function from another page? Can I save it on a DOM or something and read it from JS?

Please provide me some ideas : ]

Comment: if old browsers aren't an issue, you can go for localstorage or sessionstorage, pretty easy to use

Comment: cookies or storage of html5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage` and `JSON.parse`.

On your first page:

```
var arrayJSON = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
sessionStorage.setItem("tabledata",arrayJSON);
```

On your second page:

```
var tableData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tabledata"));
```

This will save the data as a string in your browser for the duration of the current session.  If you want it to be stored more permanently, you can use localStorage instead of sessionStorage (same syntax) and it will be stored even if the user closes the browser and comes back later.

There's more on sessionStorage and localStorage at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Thank you ; ) But the code, which you told I should put on second page returns null. Array on the first page is stored successfully. Maybe do you know why?

Comment: Is this all happening from the same domain/session?

Comment: Yes it is - I've tried with normal values, not arrays and it worked :). Maybe something is wrong with JSON parsing?

Comment: @pawel If you were copying my code directly it was missing a parentheses.  That might be the issue.  Its fixed now

Comment: Works great - mistake was mine ; ) Thank you!